# How do I slow down a SQL Server VIEW?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to use `WAITFOR` in a SQL Server View?

I have a view that is being referenced by a few applications and I need to introduce some slowness to the view to do some application testing (to test how well they handle it).

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to edit this view and make it run slowly.

Comment: You could intentionally cause performance issues by cross joining it to something big then using distinct. You'd get the same result, it's just take a lot more work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `VIEW` is not a program - in fact SQL DML statements themselves are not programs at all: they do not represent a series of instructions. Instead they're a representation of [relational-algebr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra)a, so the idea of having a delay in them is meaningless.

I note that a `VIEW` is ultimately always referenced by a `SELECT` statement. You can add delays *around* the SELECT if it's inside a `PROCEDURE` or non-inline `FUNCTION`, but as others have said, you cannot add a delay between rows in a SQL Server result set.

> I have a view that is being referenced by a few applications and I need to introduce some slowness to the view to do some application testing (to test how well they handle it).

I think a better way of testing this is to use *actual testing tools*, such as a mocking, stub, or fakes system.

Assuming it's a .NET system you're targeting, you could subclass `SqlDataReader` that has an `await Task.Delay(100)` inside the `virtual MoveNextAsync` method, for example.

If you don't have any way of modifying the application's source code, you could use a network speed limiter to artificially reduce your computer's network speed to less than a kilobyte-per-second.

Another approach might be to write a custom script for Wireshark that detects and parses TDS (Table Data Stream, SQL Server's wire protocol) and proxies it as a new server while inserting delays of its own. This may be the best approach for a long-term solution as it lends itself well to other projects - you or your company could sell it as a database latency testing tool and make a nice little earning from it.

Finally, you could switch from a `VIEW` to a `CURSOR` that has a `WAITFOR DELAY` step between each `FETCH` instruction - but this may require changing the application source code extensively, and for little gain as queries generated from stateless components (inline functions, views, and `SELECT`) will always have a better runtime execution plan and provable correctness. (Cursors are a legacy from xBase-style databases - avoid them, only use them if your query cannot be expressed as a `SELECT`).

Answer (score 3):

There's no way that you can make a SQL view have a delay. It doesn't even really make sense to do so.

If you really want to introduce some wait time, you could theoretically build a stored procedure that sleeps, then returns the results of your query.

Alternatively, you could introduce the slow down into your application logic (which makes more sense).

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, the applications are black boxes to me... I don't have access to the code... but I do have access to the views they are calling, hence my question.  I'll seek out other options.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. 
You could use a stored procedure instead to achieve this functionality.